# Как вывести компьютер из спящего режима?

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Можно ли вывести компьютер из спящего режима средствами питон 3 ? Windows 8. Подскажите библиотеки или в какую сторону рыть?

Answer (score 2):

Создайте задачу в планировщике задач и поставьте галочку "Разрешить выводить компьютер из спящего режима"

Comment: python pyqt5 pyinstaller другой компьютер т.е. программа должна запустить не мой компьютер

Comment: @Александр, через питон создайте команду в планировщике задач. Задачи можно и через консольные команды создавать

Answer (score 0):

На удаленном компьютере войдите в настройки сетевого адаптера. Там есть что то типа "Разрешить этому устройству выводить компьютер из спящего режима".
Установите эту галочку.

После этого пропингуйте компьютер. Простейший путь это использование системного вызова system ('ping computer-name')

Comment: В зависимости от настроек, обычный пинг может и не разбудить компьютер. Мой сервер, к примеру, если к нему обращаться по IP, точно проигнорирует. :) Можно создать запрет и на "ping computer-name". Хотя идея, в принципе, здравая, но писать придётся много :)